# Failure to update ADALiOS to 1.2.9 version

Tags: ios, office365, adal

My native iOS app connects to office 365 through `ADALiOS` through `Cocoapods`.
Currently it is using `ADALiOS 1.2.4` and `Office365 0.11.0.`
With the new iOS 10 update, the log in to office 365 is not working.
AS per ADAL site, it is require to update the library to `1.2.9` version.

Below is the pod file which i am using to update:

```
`pod 'Office365', '~>0.11.0'
pod 'ADALiOS', '~>1.2.9'

target 'Compen10' do

end
```

With this, the 'pod update' command throwing the error mentioned below:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> ADALiOS (~> 1.2.9) required by Podfile
>
> ADALiOS (~> 1.2.9) required by Podfile
>
> ADALiOS (= 1.2.4) required by orc (0.2.0)

Comment: Looks like you need to log an issue with the ORC repository to get them to update their dependency https://github.com/OfficeDev/orc-for-ios

Comment: I guess the other thing you could try is to fork ORC, modify the pod spec and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with updating ADALiOS in one library, but resolved it by forking this library and changing dependency inside it. The interface is the same, so nothing bad should happen.

You can point to your own repository in cocoapods using this:

```
pod 'Office365', :git => 'https://github.com/michalcichon/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS.git', :commit => '0f9879d928f67159a330324de6659c9e48bf3208'
```